# What is the font used on the scoreboard of "Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege"?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

The following screenshot is a scoreboard from an online game, *Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege*.

[image: the scoreboard from the game]

I've tried matching it on multiple sites like Font Squirrel's Matcherator and WhatFontIs, with some fonts coming close like the [FF Good Pro Extra Condensed Bold](https://www.fonts.com/font/fontfont/ff-good/extra-condensed-bold), but the "a" has a little curly and the "g" looks slightly off.

Specifically the names please, I'm not sure that the top-left text is the same as the names.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  We have some [special guidelines for font identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366). Can you please review these, then [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/130616/edit) to provide the missing information. Thanks.

Comment: @BillyKerr Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scout Condensed, available at [fontlot.com](https://fontlot.com/13072/scout/)

[image]